# Streaming data from SQL to Mongo

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, meteor

I am working with industrial equipment that inserts some text data into a SQL Server 2008 database every time it cycles (about every 25 seconds).  I am looking to forward that data to a mongo database in real time to use with an internal Meteor application.

Would there be any obvious starting point?  The closest answer I have found is at: https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/datalayer.md

> **Q: Well, how am I suppose to use the data in my SQL database then?**
>   Through REST interfaces and/or exposing the SQL database as a JSON stream. We put the ORM outside of Meteor. So, the trick is to move your data from your SQL database into Meteor's Mongo database, and have Mongo act as an object store or caching layer.

Apologies, if it is something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Mongo, but as simple repository for your MySql database.

This maintains all Meteor's characteristics and uses Mongo as a temporal repository for your MySql or PostgreSql databases.

A brilliant attempt to that is mysql-shadow by @perak (https://github.com/perak/mysql-shadow). It does what it says, keeps Mongo synchronized both ways with MySql and let's you work your data in MySql.

The bad news is that the developer will not continue maintaining it, but what is done is enough to work with simple scenarios where you don't have complex triggers that update other tables or stuff like that.

This works with MySql of course, but if you look at the code the MS SQL implementation is not  hard.

For a full featured synchronization you can use SymmetricsDS (http://www.symmetricds.org), a very well tested database replicator. This involves setting up a new java server, of course, but is by far the best way to be sure that you will be able to convert your Mongo database in a simple repository of your real MySql, PostgreSQL, SQL Server , Informix database. I have to check it myself yet.

For now MySQL Shadow seems like a good enough solution.

One advantage of this approach is that you can still use all standard Meteor features, packages, meteor deployment and so on. You don´t have to do anything but set up the synch mechanism, and you are not breaking anything.

Also, if someday the Meteor team uses some of the dollars raised in SQL integration, your app is more likely to work as is.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will report back.

Comment: I ended up going with SymmetricDS.  I have to set it up under the free version, but I can figure that out. Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: Great. You are welcome BTW, you can still use AlaSql (which is now available as meteor package) to do joins in you normalized Mongo client documents.